# Why google and facebook login not working after publishing on google play store

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My app has sign in via google and facebook buttons, they are working well when I export release the apk but they aren't working when I publish it on google play store.

I tried putting `SHA-1 certificate fingerprint` on firebase specifically to add finger button I get the following error message.

`An OAuth2 client already exists for this package name and SHA-1 in another project. You can omit the SHA-1 for now and read more about this situation and how to resolve it.`

Honestly, I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely need to add the combination of the release apk SHA-1 and app ID to your project in the console.  If you can't do that, [contact Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).